# Python pattern search return only inside quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re, python-pattern

need help with the output. As of now it outputs the entire line

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('Computer([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])Properties')
with open("Test.xml") as f:
    for line in f:
            if pattern.search(line):
                print(line)
```

Result

```
          <Computer0Properties name="BRSM">

          </Computer0Properties>

          <Computer1Properties name="4U-142">

          </Computer1Properties>
```

What I want no quotes or anything around the results

```
BRSM
4U-142
```

Have tried

```
print(re.findall(r"(\"[\w\s]+\")",line ))
```

it outputs

```
['"BRSM"']
[]
[]
```

completly missing the second result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f:
        #parse each line returned and return only the names inside the quote
        resultName = re.findall('"([^"]*)"',line )
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile('Computer([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])Properties')
with open("Test.xml") as f:
    for line in f:
            if pattern.search(line):
                print(line.split("\"", 4)[1], line.split("\"", 4)[3])
                     #BRSM                    4U-142
```

Comment: this will be used on a file with over 1m lines
your code would be out of range in terms of index